# Writing a loop for randomly selecting rows of a matrix and doing a linear regression on data from rows and storing in a matrix

Tags: r, loops, random

I need to write a program that does the following in R:

I have a data set (42 rows, 2 columns) of y variables and x variables.

I want to randomly select 12 rows from this matrix and record the coefficients (slope and intercept) of a linear regression of the randomly generated matrix. I would also like to write a loop for this so I can repeat this 1000 times, so I can then have a matrix with 1000 rows and 2 columns filled in with the slopes and intercepts of the 1000 randomly selected sets of 12 rows from my data set.

I am able to get this far but do not know how to incorporate a loop into the code, and a way to store the coefficients into a a matrix.

```
#Box.Z and Box.DC.gm are columns of data used to generate my initial matrix of data

A <- matrix(c(Box.Z, Box.DC.gm), nrow=42)
B <- A[sample(42, 12), ]
C <- lm(B[,2] ~ B[,1])
D <- matrix(c(coefficients(C)), ncol =2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
#set.seed(23)
A <- matrix(runif(84),ncol=2)

randco <- function(A) {
  B <- A[sample(42,12),]
  lm(B[,2] ~ B[,1])$coefficients
}

t(replicate(10,randco(A)))

#      (Intercept)        B[, 1]
# [1,]   0.6018459 -0.1643174222
# [2,]   0.4411607  0.0005322798
#...
# [9,]   0.3201649  0.4848679516
#[10,]   0.5413830  0.1850853748
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response here. I have data in rows in a matrix that I need to run the regression on so I'm not sure how to include this in the code. I am a beginnner in R code, so I am not quite sure what the "Set.seed(23)" part of the code is doing. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jason - I have updated to use a matrix as the input. The `set.seed` bit is just setting the random number generator so that you will get the same result to make sure the code works the same for you. It's not overly necessary to the rest of the answer.

Comment: I really appreciate the help and your code is excellent. My only question is if I have a matrix of data "A <- matrix(c(Box.Z, Box.DC.gm), nrow=42)", how would I load that data into this code, instead of random numbers?

Comment: @Jason - just replace the `A <- ...` line in my answer with your `A <- matrix(c(Box.z ...` code and everything should just work.